# How to delete numbers in Excel Filter

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2016

I have data from A to F column and I want to filter in E column and delete the entire row which contains # and only numbers. (Check image). I used the code and it works for #, but numbers not. In filter the 'Number filter' is not availble so i cant record in macro.

How to change the code? Help me, please.

[image]

```
Sub Macro3()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rng1 As Range

Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set rng1 = ws.Range(ws.[A2], ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp))

With ActiveSheet
        .AutoFilterMode = False
        rng1.AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="#"
        rng1.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Delete
        .AutoFilterMode = False
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: use `Criteria1:=">=0"` to get all values that are numbers only.

Comment: You could use a helper column to get numerical values and delete these rows using a filter `TRUE` or `FALSE`. In case there are textual numbers use a solution like [here](https://superuser.com/questions/589597/check-if-excel-cell-text-is-numeric-using-formula-only).

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Thank you for the idea. Its Working!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Criteria1:=">=0"` to find all numbers.

```
rng1.AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:=">=0", Operator:=xlAnd

Dim RowsToDelete As Range
On Error Resume Next
Set RowsToDelete = rng1.Resize(RowSize:=rng1.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(RowOffset:=1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow
On Error GoTo 0

If Not RowsToDelete Is Nothing Then RowsToDelete.Delete
```

Note:

- `rng1.Resize(RowSize:=rng1.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(RowOffset:=1)`
  removes the header from rng1 selection
- `.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow`
  selects only the visible cells of the filtered range.

Comment: @peh If No numbers are available then it shows error. 'No cells were found'

Comment: @Deepak you need to add error handling then. See my edit.